# Change background color of today in calendarview UWP

Tags: uwp, calendarview

How can I change the color of today's background in CalendarView?

[image: CalendarView]

Always thank you in advance..!

Comment: `CalendarDayViewItem` does not contain specific style that can be modified according to [official documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/9fac8c72-02da-44d6-a5be-7b67be5540c3). so either you use the default template, add your own VisualStates and then create background. Or you can subscribe to `CalendarViewDayItemChanging` event and then change the background of Today's Date. See [Here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d2174a90-c417-4294-9e99-44d5a0280c56/uwp-calendarview-today-background-color?forum=wpdevelop) for Example.

Answer (score 5):

The style key you need to override to customize the color used when IsTodayHighlighted="True" is `SystemControlHighlightAccentBrush`

```
<CalendarView>
  <CalendarView.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SystemControlHighlightAccentBrush" Color="Green" />
  </CalendarView.Resources>
</CalendarView>
```

Comment: This answer is perfect

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this with not much of an effort using c#. And to be honest it's much better than writing up a style for such a trivial thing. Below is how you do it:

1. Subscribe to the `CalendarViewDayItemChanging` event of the `CalendarView`
2. Write up the code to change the color, something like below:

---

```
  private void CalendarView_CalendarViewDayItemChanging(CalendarView sender, CalendarViewDayItemChangingEventArgs args)
  {
      if (args.Item.Date.Date.Equals(DateTime.Now.Date))
          args.Item.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);
  }
```

While your XAML declaration looks like below:

```
<CalendarView CalendarViewDayItemChanging="CalendarView_CalendarViewDayItemChanging"/>
```

Comment: @JeremyF. I upvoted but i can't accept it as answer look at the question which wasn't asked by me 

Comment: @Shubham Sahu Sorry!